# Xamarin On Windows C#

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-assembly

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. (MSB3644) (FirstConsoleProject)

How to fix?

New to coding and need some help thanks!

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what is wrong, and **exactly** what you need to do to fix it. What more do you want from us? The first thing you should learn is that the words in error messages contain meaning, and that you need to **read them** in order to get that information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error message already says exactly how to resolve the problem, so it's unclear what the issue is. Please also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

First off, there's not really a question here, you just posted an error message with no context, is anything breaking? If so, what?

You need to analyze the error message before asking your question. To start, the global assembly cache is a place on your machine that Windows uses to reference commonly used assemblies, so when it says that it will use those instead, all that means is that you may get different versions than what you had intended or other slight differences, the reason that is significant is it doesn't really tell me that there is an issue, only that you haven't referenced the proper dll's somehow so Windows is letting you know it's going to fall back to using the GAC.

All of this to say, based on your error message, there is no real issue, the GAC works just fine. If there is an issue and the GAC isn't giving you the correct dll's, then you need to tell us that, and you need to tell us what dll's you are trying to use.